# Warning: mysql_fetch_object(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in functions.php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with `mysql_fetch_object` in the code below. Please help me to fix.

```
$query .= 'order by ts_uploaded DESC' ;

$result = mysql_query($query);


// format the return data, allows us to create key for thumbname
$items = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
    $items[$row->id]['id']          = $row->id;
    $items[$row->id]['filename']    = $row->filename;
    $items[$row->id]['status']      = $row->status;
    $items[$row->id]['format']      = $row->format;
    $items[$row->id]['title']       = $row->title;
    $items[$row->id]['duration']    = $row->duration;
    $items[$row->id]['thumbnail']   = getThumbname($row->filename);
    $items[$row->id]['width']       = $row->width;
    $items[$row->id]['height']      = $row->height;
}

return $items;
```

}

Comment: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php)

Comment: Did you try any debugging? Have a look what's inside `$result`? Checked [for an error](http://ca2.php.net/mysql_error)?

Comment: Please post your full $query

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your mysql query. Try doing an:

```
echo $query;
echo mysql_error();
```

after the mysql_query statement and see what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The warning means that mysql_fetch_object() do not have a valid result set in argument so mysql_query() is not returning it

Check your sql which was passed to mysql_query(), it is not given here.

Please note this also from php.net:

mysql extension Warning:

This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the [MySQLi](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used. See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and related FAQ for more information. Alternatives to this function include: